# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list 5

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm getting

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list 5

```js
(function(event){
    showAddress( amgoan gondia);
    return true;
})
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="showAddress(<s:property value="getAddress()"/>)return true;">
```

Comment: Please provide more detailed info about your issue

Comment: The `onclick` handler is parsed as `onclick="showAddress(<s:property value="`. You need to escape the quotes.

Comment: Please provide the code segment which without it you don't get the error. Make sure you post it aligned, currently it is not readable.

Comment: (function(event){showAddress( Hostel Block 2, Ambazari, Nagpur, Maharashtra 440010, India )return false;
})     i am full address onclick how resolve problem Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Answer (score 0):

```
showAddress( amgoan gondia);
```

This one is wrong.

There should be no space in parameter list

Write in this way.

```
showAddress( amgoan, gondia);
```

If it is single parameter then concat with separator like `_`

```
showAddress( amgoan_gondia);
```

Comment: (function(event){showAddress( Hostel Block 2, Ambazari, Nagpur, Maharashtra 440010, India )return false;
})     i am full address onclick how resolve problem Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: but this retrieve form the database

Comment: Is this while signature is retrived from database?

Comment: try to put single or double quote around parameter in argument list in Database itself

Comment: dear sir i am solve problem  i am giving ( ' amgon gondia ') thank you for suggestion

Comment: If is helpfull then please mark it so we can close it

Answer (score 0):

For me it was single and double '' "" problem:
it was : var jsonMap = JSON.parse("${pageBean.getJsonMap('')}");
it should be : var jsonMap = JSON.parse('${pageBean.getJsonMap("")}');